# Unable to compile a Rust builder pattern because a borrowed value does not live long enough

Tags: rust, builder

I am trying to use the [builder pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/method-syntax.html#builder-pattern) in Rust, however I am getting a compilation error.

```
pub struct DynamicParams {
    port: Option<u16>,
} 

impl DynamicParams {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        DynamicParams { port: None }
    }

    pub fn port(&mut self, port: u16) -> &mut Self {
        self.port = Some(port);
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let params = DynamicParams::new().port(1);
}
```

It's [available on play.rust-lang.org](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=pub%20struct%20DynamicParams%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20port%3A%20Option%3Cu16%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20DynamicParams%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20new()%20-%3E%20Self%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20DynamicParams%20%7B%20port%3A%20None%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20fn%20port(%26mut%20self%2C%20port%3A%20u16)%20-%3E%20%26mut%20Self%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.port%20%3D%20Some(port)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20params%20%3D%20DynamicParams%3A%3Anew().port(1)%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Error:

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> <anon>:17:18
   |>
17 |>     let params = DynamicParams::new().port(1);
   |>                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ does not live long enough
note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 17:46...
  --> <anon>:17:47
   |>
17 |>     let params = DynamicParams::new().port(1);
   |>                                               ^
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the statement at 17:4
  --> <anon>:17:5
   |>
17 |>     let params = DynamicParams::new().port(1);
   |>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
   --> <anon>:17:5
   |>
17 |>     let params = DynamicParams::new().port(1);
   |>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

However as near as I can see, this is very similar to the [builder pattern, as described in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/method-syntax.html#builder-pattern). What's going on? What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Rust 1.11.

Comment: I asked a concise Question for this common rust error `error[E0716]` [error E0716: temporary value dropped while borrowed (rust)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626083/error-e0716-temporary-value-dropped-while-borrowed-rust). It links back to this Question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing a finalizing method returning an owned object, like:

```
pub fn finalize(&self) -> DynamicParams {
    DynamicParams { port: self.port }
}
```

When you have it you can do the following:

```
let params = DynamicParams::new().port(1).finalize();
```

Which works, because the right hand expression does not return a reference, but an owned object. `port()` only returns a mutable reference; the object created by `new()` would have to be introduced by an earlier `let` binding in order for a reference to it to be valid.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed my getter methods to work on owned objects, and return that. Not references. Then I don't need the `.finalize()`